# Javascript onclick pick random html element and style it

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, onclick

Hello I am need some help with javascript
I am newbie self-taught

How can i code - I have a table and 2 buttons, when i press button I want to pick random table data (from 1 to 9) and change it background color

and when i press second button - change table data from 1 to 9 in order.

// my javascript knowledge is very low but i understand that i need to 
give id for my each table data, 
a button with onclick="random()", 
function random () - but i dont know how to pick random ID i gave for my td

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">

  //function random() {
  // var myArray = new Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9");
  //  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);}
 
  document.getElementById("random").onclick = function () {

   document.getElementById("1").style.backgroundColor = "red";

  }

 </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Javascript homework</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <style type="text/css">
  
 table {

  border: 1px solid black;

 }

 th, td {

  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  border: 1px solid black;

 }
 </style>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
     <div class="col-md-6"> 
      <table>
       <tr>
        <td id="1">1</td>
        <td id="2">2</td>
        <td id="3">3</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td id="4">4</td>
        <td id="5">5</td>
        <td id="6">6</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td id="7">7</td>
        <td id="8">8</td>
        <td id="9">9</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      <button id="random" type="button" onclick="random()">Random</button>
      <button id="next" type="button" onclick="next()">Next</button>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us your code and whatever you've tried that isn't working.

Comment: Please, make sure to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: bad javascript code i know ,
i know how to change element on click but not random element
in comment im trying come up with array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited:

See comments inside js:

```js
function random(){
    //make a collection with all td elements
    var items = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

    for( i=0; i < items.length; i++ ){
        //that delete old backgroundColor style 
        items[i].style.backgroundColor = '';
    };
    //choose a random id between 1 and 9
    var random_id = Math.floor((Math.random()*9)+1);
    //aply the red style color to this random element
    document.getElementById(random_id).style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Javascript homework</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <style type="text/css">
  
 table {

  border: 1px solid black;

 }

 th, td {

  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;

 }
 </style>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
     <div class="col-md-6"> 
      <table>
       <tr>
        <td id="1">1</td>
        <td id="2">2</td>
        <td id="3">3</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td id="4">4</td>
        <td id="5">5</td>
        <td id="6">6</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td id="7">7</td>
        <td id="8">8</td>
        <td id="9">9</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      <button id="random" type="button" onclick="random()">Random</button>
      <button id="next" type="button" onclick="next()">Next</button>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer?

Comment: thx its works
but how can i do that after second click only 1 element would be red?

Comment: @kblok I think you mean about this Math.floor((Math.random()*(9-1))+1);. I vaguely remembered a random function between two numbers. The correct one was  **Math.floor (Math.random () * (max-min + 1) + min);**  but between 1-9 not need 9-1+1. I have edited with the right random now

Comment: @MTK I was going through answers marked as "Low quality posts" the community doesn't like neither code-only posts or link-only posts.

Comment: @AlexJ. See mi edited answer that respond also about your second question

Comment: @MTK thanks you, yes its works. i still need figure out with "for"  but i think i will understand it

Comment: @AlexJ Take a look here to understand the for loop: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just return a random number between 1 and 9 (See random function). Use `document.getElementById` to select that element, and set it to red.

See below:

```js
function random() {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
}
 
document.getElementById("random").onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById(random()).style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Javascript homework</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <style type="text/css">
  
 table {

  border: 1px solid black;

 }

 th, td {

  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;

 }
 </style>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
     <div class="col-md-6"> 
      <table>
       <tr>
        <td id="1">1</td>
        <td id="2">2</td>
        <td id="3">3</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td id="4">4</td>
        <td id="5">5</td>
        <td id="6">6</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td id="7">7</td>
        <td id="8">8</td>
        <td id="9">9</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      <button id="random" type="button" onclick="random()">Random</button>
      <button id="next" type="button" onclick="next()">Next</button>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thx its works
but how can i do that after second click only 1 element would be red?